# Search Listview using Textbox in C# from SQL Database

Tags: c#, sql, listview, search

I use followng code in **VB.Net** to search data in listview using TextBox. This code was **VB.NET** i have changed this to **C#** according to my understanding as i am new to **C#** but this is not working.

```
private void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Vendors Where VendorName Like'%" + TextBox1.Text + "%' or VendorID Like'%" + TextBox1.Text + "%'", con);
    SqlDataReader reader;
    con.Open();
    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    cmd.Dispose();
    ListView1.Items.Clear();
    if (reader.HasRows)
    {
        while (reader.Read()) 
        {
            **ListView1.Items.Add(reader[0]);**
            ListView1.Items[ListView1.Items.Count - 1].SubItems.Add(reader.**item**[1]);
            ListView1.Items[ListView1.Items.Count - 1].SubItems.Add(reader.**Item**[2]);
            ListView1.Items[ListView1.Items.Count - 1].SubItems.Add(reader.Item[3]);
        }
    }
    reader.Close();
    con.Close();
}
```

i am getting error here `ListView1.Items.Add(reader[0])` and here `(reader.item[1])` (Where typed item of all 3 columns) could anyone point out correct this code. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

From this point of view, I can see that you haven't created a object of `ListViewItem` class, and also here `ListView1.Items.Add(reader[0])` you didn't cast your indexer,so maybe that is the reason why you got the error

So, first you need to create object of `ListViewItem` class, then add all of `SubItems` on that Item, and at the end you need to add that **Item** to your `ListView1`

It will be something like this

```
private void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Vendors Where VendorName Like'%" + TextBox1.Text + "%' or VendorID Like'%" + TextBox1.Text + "%'", con);
    SqlDataReader reader;
    con.Open();
    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    cmd.Dispose();
    ListView1.Items.Clear();
    if (reader.HasRows)
    {
        while (reader.Read()) 
        {

            ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(reader[0].ToString()); // Or you can specify column name - ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(reader["column_name"].ToString()); 
            item.SubItems.Add(reader[1].ToString());
            item.SubItems.Add(reader[2].ToString());
            item.SubItems.Add(reader[3].ToString());
            ListView1.Items.Add(item); // add this item to your ListView with all of his subitems
        }
    }
    reader.Close();
    con.Close();
}
```